# Getting [object][object] when trying to display data from api service

Tags: json, angular, api

There are similar questions out there on StackOverflow but not exactly like mine.

When I check the Network tab in Inspector the data is being pulled from the api service. However, when I try to call it to the page I get [object][object].

Here's the structure of the data:
Object.widget.Value ... I would like to display the Value.

Here's how I am currently trying to call it:
{{i.widget}}

I've also tried json stringify and "| json" and those get me "undefined".

All other data that exists on the same level as widget is displaying fine and formatted the same. For some reason I can't pull widget's value.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

if this's what API return to us:

```
{name: "fox"}
```

in our `component` we can get it as:

```
data: any;

this.service.getData().subscribe((response) => {
   this.data = response.body;
});
```

in our `view` if we put `{{data}}` it will return `[object][object]`, you should set an `property` too in this case we have `name` which equal to `fox`, for example: `{{data.name}}`;

Comment: Why response.body..?

Comment: If you active options in the `httpClient` and set `{observe: 'events'}` you will get `status` and `body`, that helps you find out what type returns to you, EX:  status = 200 or 400 or 401